How have fiber optic bandwidths improved over time?
I want to build a sense of how fiber optic transceiver technology has improved over time, and what relevant physical limits constrain it in the limit.
For instance, ChatGPT tells me that in 2010 typical bandwidths were in the order of 10 Gbps per wavelength, while now I see systems deployed that achieve 100 Gbps. Is this right?
Complementarily, how has the possible range of DWDM channels increased over time? My understanding is that standard DWMD technology allows for simultaneous use of 80 bands. Is this right? Has this changed much over time?
The ideal answer to this question would look like a timeline with examples of long range connections achieved at some years, including their cost and capacity.

I humbly implore, stop asking ChatGPT about technical engineering questions. Unless you know the subject well enough to quality check the output of the text generator, the answer is worse than no answer. It is extremely good at "sounding" convincing, but it does not "know" anything and the answer might be wildly wrong and you are none the wiser. Ergo worse off than when you knew you didn't know anything.

@MrGerber I agree, hence why I asked here

yeah, you can forget anything that chatgpt wrote, it's wrong totally wrong. It's better to not ask ChatGPT to begin with, and not end up with incorrect presumptions.

@MarcusMüller Fully agreed. Is the specific datoid here wrong tho? Is it true that bandwidth per overnight dollar has increased by 10x since 2010?

10gbit is a lot older than 2010 so yes they're pretty suspect. Probably worth checking Wikipedia if you want to know the specific years.

@Jsevillamol completely and utterly wrong. 10 Gb/s was not state of the art in 2010; "per dollar" is a hard question, because: does that incorporate distance? transporting 100 Gb/s on an optical backplane is cheaper than transporting it over 2000 km. Different technologies have different cost per bits per second per watt per meter tradeoffs, and nobody here can give you a five-dimensional sketch of what was available at which time.

Nah, forget anything that ChatGPT told you. Don't even start asking ChatGPT for such things – you just end up with incorrect prenotions.
By 2010, industry was heavily in the process of standardizing 100 Gb/s ethernet, but that was mostly denser 10 Gb/s optic transceivers with multi-fiber cables. However, by 2014, 28 Gb/s transceivers were standard.
HOWEVER, this is just the typical "cheap" intensity modulated transmission – many of the commercial standards aren't even 4-PAM, they're just PAM2 (which I would call OOK, potentially with an offset), obviously staying large factors behind the actual channel capacity, and also staying behind what was technologically possible per wavelength at the time.
To speak of what was technologically feasible (but maybe not in the cheap data center rack switch), around 2009, Alcatel-Lucent (later Bell Labs) already achieved 100 Gb/s per wavelength, 2011 we're at more than 250 Gb/s/wavelength at NEC, in 2016 Bell Labs together with TU Munich achieve 1 Tb/s. This is all over standard single mode fibers. And we're talking distances in the order of 100 km.
At that point (around 32 Gbd, i.e., 32 billion symbols per second), you've roughly reached the maximum bandwidth we can currently modulate onto the electrical field of light, physically. Your only remaining optimization opportunity is to put more bits on each symbol.
And where boring technology that is in glossy marketing material from hundreds of IT companies, so, what ChatGPT can even know about, only uses 2 bits or fewer per symbol (by using 4 different intensities), in the 2010s, coherent modulation was standard in long-haul (read: submarine) connections. And by 2016, 64-QAM, a modulation that has 64 different complex values (rather than just 4 amplitudes, it also uses phase), a so-called constellation with 64 points, to transport (log2(64)=) 6 bit per symbol, was a "basic example benchmark for researchers to be better than".
So, with better modelling of the physics of such optical fibers, and better understanding of the error-correcting codes, and better understanding of how to design constellations for nonlinear channels, the Nokia and TU Munich people designed and demonstrated a 1 Tb/s system.
Since then, advantages on the front of better design methodology, better error correction, better synchronization etc have been made – but that result was already so close to the theoretical mathematical limits of how fast it is to transport data in a given bandwidth, that it's basically impossible that we'll see large increases on the per-wavelength throughput.
For that, bandwidths of modulators would need to increase, and that might theoretically happpen, but at some point you're making your equalization problem worse by having more bandwidth per wavelength, rather than having multiple wavelengths very close to each other. There's still enough research in all these fields – including optimization of transmitter constellation shaping across wavelengths to keep the nonlinear intermodulation in the same fiber at bay, but I don't foresee us seeing a 2 Tb/s system. The justification for going even higher-bandwidth on a single wavelength is just not there, physically.

This is great thank you!
